# Is Bootstrap really easier than just writing responsive CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've just barely looked into Bootstrap, and from what I can see, I'll also need to get used to using less CSS.

However, responsive CSS doesn't seem difficult to me. When it is difficult, it's usually because my layout is very complex, and the majority of work boils down to wireframing out my content before I even get to writing the responsive CSS for it, and if there's ever a time where I want to write my own code from scratch, this is it..

- So what is the appeal with Bootstrap?
- Why do developers rather use it than just code their own CSS?
- Is it only used for quick one off small websites, or simple layouts like blogs?

My primary question is **What makes using Bootstrap easier than writing responsive CSS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always beneficient to use bootstrap, however you get a lot with the package and it will save you a lot of time if you use it correctly. You also by default get a really good CSS structure which many developers struggle with when their app grows.

In my opinion there are times when you should write your own css, for instance if you have a very unique/complex design that break the bootstrap pattern of building sites.

You can use bootstrap for both small and big sites, that doesn't really matter. The decision wether to use it or not rather lays in if you are willing to build your site following their type of structure. With a GRID system for example.

And yes, building your own responsive css isnt that hard, but can be time-consuming. With bootstrap you get a lot for free